# Simple .BAT file rename issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

Okay, so here's my issue.

I have a program (`program1`) that when run looks for an INI file that has info about the user stored in it (`userinfo.ini`). The program does not support multiple users, so my idea is to have two INI files, one for `user1` and another for `user2`. The INI file name, however, *has* to remain named `userinfo.ini` or `program1` won't recognize that it exists.

So here was my plan,

I have two INI files in the root folder of the program. One is named `userinfo.ini.USER1` and the other is named `userinfo.ini.USER2`.

When the BAT file for `user1` is clicked, I want it to check to see if `userinfo.ini.USER1` exists, and if so rename `userinfo.ini` to `userinfo.ini.USER2` and then rename `userinfo.ini.USER1` to `userinfo.ini`. If `userinfo.ini.USER1` doesn't exist, it will do nothing.

The BAT file for `user2` would do essentially the same thing, just flipped.

Once that's done, the BAT file is to execute `program1`.

Here's the code I have written for that:

```
IF EXIST userinfo.ini.USER1
ren userinfo.ini userinfo.ini.USER2
ren userinfo.ini.USER1 userinfo.ini

START program1.exe
```

However, when run, CMD tells me `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

How do I have this coded incorrectly, and how should it be coded to accomplish my goal?

Thank you for all help beforehand, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if exist file` doesn't make any sense, so you get a syntax error. You need a command statement after it (`if exist file echo yes`). You can do several commands as a statement using `(` and `)`:

```
IF EXIST userinfo.ini.USER1 (
  ren userinfo.ini userinfo.ini.USER2
  ren userinfo.ini.USER1 userinfo.ini
)
START program1.exe
```

Be sure, that the first `(` is on the same line that your `if`

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for your help. Out of curiosity though, you said I needed an echo statement, but then in the code your provided, there was no echo. What did you mean by that?

Comment: you don't need an `echo`, just a command statement. `echo` was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: Instead of renaming anything, why not just copy them?

User1.bat:

```
copy userinfo.ini.USER1 userinfo.ini
START program1.exe
```

User2.bat:

```
copy userinfo.ini.USER2 userinfo.ini
START program1.exe
```

Comment: this was also my first thought. But what, if `program1.exe` makes changes to the ini-file (like writing "last login date")?

Comment: You could add /WAIT to the START line so the batch file waits for program1 to end, then execute the reverse by adding another line to each: copy userinfo.ini userinfo.ini.USER?  I offered it as I did because the asker didn't mention anything about the ini files changing but that's a good question.